# pulldown command menu options

Tags: java

I've added a pulldown command to my toolbar

```
<command
    commandId="my.uri.Options"
    label="%Options.label"
    icon="icons/properties.png"
    style="pulldown">
</command>
```

that under a pull down menu have some toggle options. 
I would like to get to those option by pushing the button as well, and not just the menu triangle. Is that possible? Or my approach is all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the `onclick` event handler, or the you could explore the `addEventListener()` to change the action for when the menu is clicked.

Comment: i do not want to change the action for the menu, i want to call it when the the button is clicked, so no matter what is clicked, button or pull down menu, the result will be the same - the pull down menu.

Comment: Oh, ok, so then can you turn the menu item itself into a link which causes the menu to drop down?  Or add an event listener to the button and the pulldown so that clicking one or the other has the same result?

Comment: thanks, i think i will not use command at all in this case, i'm adding a button to a tool bar instead and adding menu to it.